# Append an integer to list N times with prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to append an integer N times to a list. So far, I know how to append two lists and I am trying to use that calling a recursive call so it appends N times an integer.

I have already tried:

```
append([],L,L).
append([H|T],L2,[H|L3]) :- append(T,L2,L3).

list(X,N,L,L2) :- N>0, append([X],L,L2), N is N-1, list(X,N,L2,L3).

% Test of the code

1 ?- list(3,6,A,B).
false.

% Expected Result

[3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use standard built-in and library predicates:

```
?- I = 3, N = 7, findall(I, between(1,N,_), L).
I = 3,
N = 7,
L = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3].
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo. And so simple :)

Answer (score 2):

yet another possibility:

```
?- length(L,6),maplist(=(3),L).
L = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3].
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful as well

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, just for fun, not recommended, lousy portability, but I do like cyclic terms:

```
?- length(List, 7), Cyclic = [3| Cyclic], prefix(List, Cyclic).
List = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
Cyclic = [3|Cyclic].
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this simple solution without append predicate ;

**EDIT :**

```
gen_list(_,0,[]) :-!. %  or : gen_list(I,1,[I]) :-!.
gen_list(I,N,[I|Is]) :- 
         N1 is N-1,
         gen_list(I,N1,Is).
```

**test :**

```
| ?- gen_list(3,6,L).
L = [3,3,3,3,3,3]
```